# symboling implications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

below is proposition:
$N: real number$

$P(a,b) \iff a | b$

$Q(a) \iff a $ is prime

Any natural number $n \ge 2$ that is not divisible by a natural number from 2 to $\sqrt n$ is prime

i made two of this

$\forall n \ge 2 , \exists x: 2 \le x \le \sqrt n , P(n,x) \implies \neg Q(n)$
$\forall n \ge 2 , \exists x: 2 \le x \le \sqrt n ,\neg P(n,x) \implies  Q(n)$

Which one is right and how can i know which one is antecedent and which one is consequent?

I think the first one is right

Comment: The second one: "A unless B" is $A \lor B$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thankyou , i change the problem to 
"Any natural number $n \ge 2$ that is not divisible by a natural number from 2 to $\sqrt n$ is prime"

Comment: Since $P(a,b)$ is "$a$ divide $b$" (e.g. $2|4$), it should be $P(x,n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is right.

The second one says that if there is one $x$ smaller than $\sqrt n$ such that $n$ is not divisible be $x$, then $n$ is prime.

According to this definition, since $\neg(3|8)$ ($3$ doesn't divide $8$), then $8$ is prime. The second definition could be change to
$$\forall n \ge 2 , \bigg(\forall x: 2 \le x \le \sqrt n ,\neg P(n,x)\bigg) \implies  Q(n)$$

Comment: Thankyou is $\forall n \ge 2 , \bigg(\forall x: 2 \le x \le \sqrt n ,\neg P(n,x)\bigg) \implies  Q(n)$ correct or not?